# How to measure software + hardware latency using tcpdump? ( Hw Timestamp)

Tags: networking, timestamps, tcpdump, latency

I have an low latency application.But it's performance is unstable. So i want to find the bottleneck if it's related to network or related to my server ( software , os etc.)

So first i tried tcpdump to measure it but i know that it does not contain kernel or nic latency correct me if i am wrong.After some investigations i found hardware timestamp that nic stamp timestamps.But i can find any example to how to use hardware timestamp(My NIC supports it, checked via ethtool -T).

How to make tcpdump gets packet timestamps from NIC's hardware timestamp?

Thank you.